# How does autoconfiguration in Spring-boot work - on example rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a some small experience with `spring-boot`. I consider if I correctly understand its way of working, on example `rabbitmq` which I am using now.

So look at my way of thinking and correct me if I am wrong, please.

---

I added to my `pom.xml` dependencies for `spring-rabbit`. Thanks to this dependency, I can use automatic configuration what does mean that during starting application `spring engine` read `application.properties`, find settings for `rabbitmq` (as host, port, queuename) and creates (register) needed beans for servicing `rabbitmq` (is this sequence of step is correct ?).

---

Now, I should be able to use `@Autowired` to get some beans (=objects form `spring` container).

---

Where is difference between `spring` and `spring-boot` in this case ?
To my eye, using `spring` I have must add all necessary beans in java code (or xml) and mark them as `@Bean` or `@Autowired`. However, in this case I must use `new` operator and be responsible for creating instance of queues and something like that.

Can you tell me if I correctly understand it ? Each additional explanation is welcome!

Comment: I think you should start from here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html

Comment: @ArtemBilan, I read but this post is to order and summarize (non)knowledge about spring-boot.